# Expected value, E(X), where does the "x" in the formula come from?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

So if we have the formulas
$$Eg(X) = \int \cdots \int g(x_1,\dots,x_k)f_X(x_1,\dots,x_k) \, dx_1\dots dx_k$$
or, for discrete,
$$Eg(X) = \sum_{x\in M} g(x)f_X(x)$$
with $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^k$ a continuous (discrete in second case) random vector with pdf (pmf) $f_X:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ any function $g:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $Eg(X)$ exists

Then, say X is the exp($\lambda)$ distribution,
$$E(X) = \int_0^\infty x \cdot \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}}dx$$

Where does that $x$ at the start of the integral come from -- the rest comes from the density function, of course. Does the x come from the function $g$, somehow? (Similarly the $x$ is there in the discrete case, if that is easier to explain).

If necessary, perhaps use the definitions $$E(X) =\int X \, dP,$$ with $P$ is a measure.

EDIT: $E(X)$ doesn't just mean $E(g(X))$ with $g(x) = x$, does it...?

Comment: It's from $g(x)$, namely, $g(x) = x$ here. Re edit: Yes, it means exactly that.

Comment: Ah, I got it and edited it at roughly the same time you commented. Thank you very much.

Comment: $x$ is just a dummy variable; it is bound in the summation/integration.

Comment: Thanks. How about an upvote too? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of expected value for a discrete random variable $X$ whose range is $0, 1, 2, ...$:

$$E(X) = 0P(X = 0) + 1P(X = 1) + 2P(X = 2) + ...$$

Let us write this compactly:

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} kP(X = k)$$

Or if you like:

$$E(X) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} xP(X = x) \ (*)$$

$x$ and $k$ are just dummies. You can use $\xi$ if you like, but I think most prefer to use the lower case of the random variable if the random variable is a capital letter.

Similarly, for all well-behaved $g$,

$$E(g(X)) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} g(x)P(X = x) \ (**)$$

If we have $g(x) = x$, then $(**)$ becomes $(*)$

Answer (score 0):

For the expected value of a random variable $X$, we have
$$E[X]=\int_{\Omega} X\ dP$$
For the expected value of a function of a random variable $X$, we have
$$E[g(X)]=\int_{\Omega} g(X)\ dP$$
The latter is a more general definition than the former. As already mentioned in the comments, the first definition is equivalent to the second definition when $g(X)=X$.